# String Concatenation with nulls on Snowflake SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have 3 columns (first name, middle name, last name) and I want to concatenate the 3 strings (to construct a full name).

However, if any of these values is null, the result is null.

What's an elegant and safe way of concatenating strings, when some of them might be null?

Comment: Thanks @SalmanA. I read the docs, and `CONCAT_WS` doesn't take care of nulls. "If any of the values is null, the result is also null"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A combination of `NVL()`/`IFNULL()` and `CONCAT_WS()` would work, but I prefer the following:

```sql
select array_to_string(array_construct_compact(column1, column2, column3), ' ')
from values('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', null, 'c')
```

- `array_construct_compact()` removes nulls.
- `array_to_string()` adds the necessary spaces when concatenating.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_construct_compact.html